# [ opens Firefox in Sublime Text 3 with Slovenian keyboard layout

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7 as my editor for HTML5,CSS,JS etc; it worked just fine until today.

When using typing `[` (which is entered as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd> on my Slovenian keyboard layout), it opens a browser.

For example, if I'm trying to write the line:

```
var array = [ "something", "in", here"];
```

As soon as I type `[`, it opens my browser.

The installed addons are::

- autosave
- emmet
- githubemoji
- sublimegit
- view in browser (this one works apart, right click and it opens ok....)

Is my question understandable enough? It's my first :)

Comment: Which OS platform is this on?

Comment: MS Windows 7....

Comment: Thanks; I've updated the question to include that detail.

Comment: [ works fine in other editors....VS Code, Notepadd++ etc...so it's Sublime related, gotta be something :P

Comment: Yes, I agree that it's Sublime related, but it could well be specific to how Sublime processes keyboard input on Windows as an individual platform.

Comment: Yep, but it did work fine till today....that annoys me :P

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled View in Browser and it's fixed now.

It can be closed now.